# How to check the availablility of a Progress database record with the values stored in a .csv file as input?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I am uploading a CSV file of records to check if these records are available in a specific Progress database table.

How do I proceed?

Comment: More information could be handy... What is stored in the .csv etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a lot of things here since you're not specifying very much.

Assuming we have a file containing animal id's, one per row:

```
file.csv
=========
1
2
3
```

Assuming we have a database table called `animals` with fields `id` and `animalName` we can do this (a very naive approach - assuming input data is well formatted, no error checking etc):

```
/* Define a temp-table to store the file data in*/
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttAnimal NO-UNDO
    FIELD id AS INTEGER.


/* Input from files */
INPUT FROM VALUE("c:\temp\file.csv").
REPEAT:

    /* Assumption: the data is clean and well formatted! */
    CREATE ttAnimal.
    IMPORT ttAnimal.


END.
INPUT CLOSE.

/* 
For each animal id read from file. Locate database record and display 
the name */
FOR EACH ttAnimal:

    FIND FIRST animal NO-LOCK WHERE animal.id = ttAnimal.id NO-ERROR.
    IF AVAILABLE animal THEN DO:
        DISP animal.animalName.
    END.

END.
```